# Good Practices to Serve Optimization System as Web App

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, architecture

## What I am Doing

I am developing optimization system with genetic algorithm; just finished PoC on JupyterNotebook and going to serve it as web application with Python3.
This optimization process needs a lot of computational resource to evaluate each candidate chromosome, so I am planning to adopt parallel distributed processing.

## How It Will Work

Below shows how this system will work (now planning).

1. Users upload file with parameters from browser and reserve optimization
2. System queues the optimization job
3. System shows reserved job list and optimization result on browser

## My Plan and Question

Here shows what I am planning (I am not familiar with web application).

1. Request to upload API and save parameters in DB and pickle
2. Check if there are any reserved optimization jobs every n minutes with cron
3. Execute optimization if need and save result in DB and update job status (waiting -> finished)

I think this will work but I am not sure this is good.
Do you know good architecture practice to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having a cron job would complicate the order flow and be inefficient. Try using a message broker (eg. rabbit-mq) and celery to schedule and run the jobs.